# How can I Serialize this class

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

however try may way tried, I do not know how can I serialize
(sorry. I found in English dictionary 'What the hell'
is this bad word? anyway i'm sorry)

1. When I use BinaryFormatter, it throw exception from RelayCommand(I want to use XmlSerializer. I must see the file's text)  
   I tried using [XmlIgnore], but i think It seems that do not apply.
2. When I use XmlSerializer, I don't know where throw exception.
3. DataContractSerializer is throw a lot of exception. so I do not want to use.

please help me. 
Please understand, I can't speak English well.

this is my class.

**Extension Solution.** 
Referred from main solution.

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializableContextBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [field: NonSerialized()]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Solution**
Main Top Level class

```
 [Serializable]
public class ResultContext : SerializableContextBase
{
    public ResultContext() { }
 private PerformanceContextCollection _PerformanceCollection = new PerformanceContextCollection();
    public PerformanceContextCollection PerformanceCollection
    {
        get { return _PerformanceCollection; }
        set
        {
            if (_PerformanceCollection == value) { return; }
            _PerformanceCollection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("PerformanceCollection");
        }
    }
```

Bottom Level Class

```
[Serializable]
public class PerformanceContextCollection : ObservableCollection<PerformanceContext>
{
   // some method  
   // public void Add(string Name){} ~~~
}

[Serializable]
public class PerformanceContext : SerializableContextBase
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public RelayCommand<PerformanceContext> RemoveCommand { get; set; }
    some string, some guid...~~
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes are designed as ViewModels, so they have a lot of extra baggage that is related to their interactions with WPF. In order to send the information to another layer, the usual reason why people serialize data, you would normally use another class, a Data Transfer Object of some sort. I know this sounds pedantic, but this solution also frees you from using the same structure when serializing. For example you might want to serialize some data as a comma separated list, instead of an entire list of elements, of you might want to ignore properties that in the ViewModel are used for ease of interaction with the WPF engine like having a Visibility property instead or together with a boolean IsVisible.

That being said, if you still want to serialize your classes as they are no matter what, the simplest way (for me at least) would be to implement [IXmlSerializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) and thus control the serialization output yourself. Understand that while the default serialization works well and usually doesn't need much developer work, it also usually renders a horrendously verbose and hard to read XML output. For example most primitive properties look better as attributes to an element, but the serialization creates child elements for each.